# Installed Ubuntu 12.04 I can't connect with internet. There isn't established a connection with the router

Tags: wireless, system-installation

From the USB installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my computer, with Windows XP in the other boot. From USB I have connection with internet without any problem. But from the computer there is the announcement **no connection with internet**.

Filled in IP address, Device MAC address, the password of the wireless connection. What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't forget any thing. It happened with me also. So you are not able to connect through wifi networks right? Have you tried connecting using a wired cable?

Actually it is the driver issue which is common to many people. What you've to do is:

1. Connect your system with wired internet connection
2. Execute following command in terminal to search and install for additional drivers:

   ```
   sudo jockey-gtk
   ```

   It will search available drivers and tried to install the missing one.
3. When finished you'll get that your wireless drivers has been installed. Just re-start your system once.

Hope it helps you. Reply if you need any clarifications.